# google stacked bar chart api with two hAxis

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, bar-chart

I am drawing an stacked bar chart using google api, I want two hAxis for graph (top one in number format and down one in % format). I am using this code for rendering graph.

Can any one suggest how to add top hAxis as number?

```
   function drawVisualization() {
      // Create and populate the data table.
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Year', 'Austria', 'Bulgaria', 'Denmark', 'Greece'],
        ['2003',1360,1001,1082,1974],
        ['2004',1556,1649,1150,1495]
      ]);

      // Create and draw the visualization.
      new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
          draw(data,
               {title:"Yearly Coffee Consumption by Country",
                width:600, height:400,
                vAxis: {title: "Year"},
                isStacked:true,
                hAxes:{0:{title:'Losses in percentage',format:'#,#%'},
                       1:{title:'Losses in number'}
                      },
                series:{0:{targetAxisIndex:0},1:{targetAxisIndex:1}} 
               }
          );
    }
    ​
```

Comment: BarCharts do not support a top hAxis.

Comment: Thanks asgallant. Which chart support ?

Comment: @asgallant ,if you see https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#Data_Format they mention in hAxes we can do.

Comment: The option exists to support multiple hAxes, but additional axes beyond the first do not render.  You can make a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/list) to add support for multiple hAxes.

Comment: I tried your code and I can't get stacked charts to display on multiple targetAxisIndex. Can anyone confirm if this works?